# Открыть диалоговое окно при нажатии на ImageView

Tags: android

В активити есть `ImageView`, в который выводится изображение. Сейчас при нажатии на `ImageView` открывается диалоговое окно для того, чтобы выбрать способ добавления изображения. Изначально в `ImageView` стоит изображение такое

```
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.noimage_bg);
```

Я бы хотел сделать так:

Если в `ImageView` картинка = `R.drawable.noimage_bg`, открыть диалоговое окно для добавления изображения, иначе если другая картинка открыть диалоговое окно для удаления изображения.

Comment: хорошо, вы хотите сделать так и эдак. в чем же вопрос?

Comment: Не знал как определить какая сейчас картинка в ImageView. Та, что я считаю стандартной R.drawable.noimage_bg или другая, которую добавил пользователь.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сохранить `id` изображения в свойстве `Tag` у `ImageView` и потом по его значению осуществлять выбор.

Отрывок примера с [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001903/get-resource-id-from-imageview):

```
image.setBackgroundResource(res);
image.setTag(res); //<------
```

Получение id и выбор по нему:

```
switch((Integer)image.getTag()){
    case 1: /*Делаем что-то*/;break;
    case 2: /*Делаем что-то*/;break;
    // и т.д.
}
```